# How to integrate $\int x\sqrt { \frac {a^2-x^2}{a^2+x^2} } \, dx$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate $\displaystyle\int  x\sqrt {\frac{a^2 - x^2}{a^2+x^2}} \,  dx$ ?

I tried this for quite some time, but not being able to solve. Help!

Comment: try $x=a\tan(t)$

Comment: Yes but after that what? Its not getting simplified! @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: $$x^2=a^2 cos2t$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$x\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2+x^2}}=x\sqrt{\frac{1-(\frac{x}{a})^2}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}}$$
and use the trigonometric identity
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}{1+\cos \theta}}=|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|$$

Comment: It should be $ \left | \tan \left(\frac\theta 2\right) \right | $

Comment: @GohP.iHan thanks , I have edited it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $~\dfrac{1+\cos2t}2=\cos^2t~$ and $~\dfrac{1-\cos2t}2=\sin^2t.$